# How can I squeeze an additional 10 FPS out of my [primitive] voxel algorithm?

Tags: javascript, 3d, dhtml, frame-rate, voxel

So, I made this simple 4dof voxel algorithm in JavaScript, and I feel quite proud of myself, but I don't have near enough time to debug and I've lost several days worth of sleep, however I notice that it's running relatively slowly.

Now, there are the obvious %-scaling and setInterval loops slowing it down, but I am getting less than 20 FPS on only 100 voxels, most of which aren't even on screen.

Please excuse the following code, it is adapted for my primitive little game engine, so it won't run on its own page, but you can test it at this URL (http://nextgengame.webs.com/fun/sandbox.htm).

```
world=new Array();

for(i=0;i<100;i++){
world[i]=[Math.random()*50-25,-3,Math.random()*50-25,['#FFFFFF','#FF0000','#00FF00','#0000FF','#FFFF33'][Math.round(Math.random()*4)]];
}

r=0;
camx=0;
camy=0;
camz=0;

fps=0;
frames=0;

window.setInterval(function(){
fps=frames;
frames=0;
},1000);

window.setInterval(function(){;
r+=0.02;
if(r>Math.PI*2)r=0;

points=[];

for(i=0;i<world.length;i++){;
u=world[i];
x1=u[0]-camx;
z1=u[2]-camz;
z2=x1*Math.sin(r)+z1*Math.cos(r);
z3=Math.round(z2);
if(!points[z3])points[z3]=[];
points[z3][points[z3].length]=[x1*Math.cos(r)-z1*Math.sin(r),u[1]-camy,z2,u[3]];
};

for(z=points.length-1;z>=0;z--){;
t=points[z];
if(t){;
for(i=0;i<t.length;i++){;
u=t[i];
z1=u[2];
z2=0-z1;
s=69/z1;
h=s*-0.5+50;
drawBox(u[0]/z1*50+h,u[1]/z2*50+h,s,s,u[3]);
};
};
};
frames+=1;
centertext(50,0,String(fps),'#FFFFFF');
sync();
},33);
```

This is hardly adequate to do a landscape or anything, and I want to get at least a 10 FPS boost.

This is what it looks like without rotations:

```
world=[];
points=[];
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
world[i]=[Math.random()*50-25,-3,Math.random()*50-25,['#FFFFFF','#FF0000','#00FF00','#0000FF','#FFFF33'][Math.round(Math.random()*4)]];
}

r=0;
camx=0;
camy=0;
camz=0;

fps=0;
frames=0;

window.setInterval(function(){
fps=frames;
frames=0;
},1000);


for(i=0;i<world.length;i++){;
u=world[i];
z3=Math.round(u[2]);
if(!points[z3])points[z3]=[];
points[z3][points[z3].length]=u;
};

window.setInterval(function(){;

for(z=points.length-1;z>=0;z--){;
t=points[z];
if(t){;
for(i=0;i<t.length;i++){;
u=t[i];
z1=u[2];
z2=0-z1;
s=69/z1;
h=s*-0.5+50;
drawBox(u[0]/z1*50+h,u[1]/z2*50+h,s,s,u[3]);
};
};
};
frames+=1;
centertext(50,0,String(fps),'#FFFFFF');
sync();
},33);
```

And would you believe it, it still runs at about the same speed! a 4 FPS increase at most!

It would really make my day if somebody had a way of running this a lot faster.

Comment: Where is your code intentation and where are your comments? Why are you making most of your variables global (including `i`)?

Comment: Shouldn't the `r-=0.02;` be `r+=0.02;`?

Comment: It is lazy coding. This is what happens when you don't understand a concept- you rush a bunch of code just to see if it works. Also, I didn't indent because I can't use the tab key, and this is all edited in-browser. @lbruder- yes it should

Comment: Post your drawBox() function?

Answer (score 3):

One obvious thing would be to have precalculated values for your radiant values, meaning that you'll have two arrays with sinus and cosinus in increments of 0.02, up to 2 x pi (which is a complete circle).

Those calculations are really heavy on the engine.

Also, you are using setInterval for the animation, however in 33 ms intervals, that leaves you with a maximum of 30 fps. the timing on setInterval isn't an exact measurement either, because it can be delayed by other factors (other timers etc), so maybe you would be better of to just try to run them as soon as possible and adjust the animation to the fps instead?

And use a setTimeout with a low value just to free up the engine for other task in between the frames., to not exhaust the CPU.

Comment: I know. After testing, I found that that's where the slowdown is, but I have no way of stopping that. I don't want to make a spinner, I want to make a full 3D game engine. However, I'd be OK with it to the nearest degree (out of 360). Could you post an example? EDIT: I disagree with you about setInterval. My only real concern is the significant slowdown caused by the sine and cosine operations.

Answer (score 0):

As ThiefMaster wrote above, use local variables (see http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jkm3). There are lots of calculations inside your loops. Could some of them be pre-calculated? Do you really need all those variables, or could the temporary ones be omitted by writing slightly more complex expressions?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I feel that variable use is the least of my problems. However, you make a valid point- sine and cosine take way too long to process, and thus I should use an array. However, I don't have the code for that, and I am way too tired. If someone could show me a working example, I would be grateful.

Comment: Do try using local variables. The lookup cost is much smaller. Using local variables often results in a surprising speedup.

Comment: Nope- it's impossible because I'm using scoped variables (with(parent){}) and an eval() statement. What you are describing may work, but I would have to restructure a lot of stuff. Is there anything more concrete and lazy, maybe a way to force the browser into "fast rendering mode" or something?